# When do I have to free allocated memory?

Tags: c, malloc, microcontroller, free

I'm new to microcontrollers and pointers and I'm not sure where to free allocated memory and if this example would work correctly:

Example 1:

```
char * function(void)
{
    char *help;
    help = malloc(sizeof(char));
    //...
    return help;
}

void main(void)
{
    char *pointer = function();
    //do something with pointer
    //do I have to free(pointer); here?
}
```

Is it possible to allocate memory for help in function and return the address, without the memory to be freed by the end of the function?

- If yes: Do I have to free the memory in main after the usage?
- If no: Is the following example working correctly?

Example 2:

```
void function(char **pointer)
{
    *pointer = malloc(sizeof(char));
    //...
}

void main(void)
{
    char *pointer;
    function(&pointer);
    //do something with pointer
    free(pointer);
}
```

Comment: Each and every pointer that has been obtained via malloc and similar functions must be freed using the free function and some point before the program ends. Of course you don't need to free the memory in the same function where it has been allocated, this requirement would make memory allocation pretty pointless. Your usage looks correct to me.

Comment: Bottom line is this. If you return the pointer to `main()` and don't need to `free` it for storage reasons, it will be freed automatically on program exit. However, that being said, you have two responsibilities regarding the memory you allocate (1) preserve a pointer to the beginning of the allocated block, so (2) it can be freed when it is no longer needed. When you begin allocating and using memory outside of `main()` it must be freed before the last function holding a pointer to the block returns -- otherwise a memory leak is created because you have no way to free the block before exit.

Comment: In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: whether you "have to" free memory depends on the application and operating system

Comment: While any reasonable OS will free memory once your process exits, I would recommend just getting in the habit of always freeing memory you allocate, even if its in main.  In case you copy parts of your code around and change the structure of your program, this makes it easier not to forget and cause memory leaks.

Comment: It will also make a difference if you are using a memory usage/error checking program such as `valgrind` for Linux. If you do not free the allocated block before exit, your allocation will still be reported as in use at program exit. It's a good habit to track your allocations and free each when done.

Comment: In both of your examples you are allocating a single char, which is probably not what you want (in most situations.)

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks!

@DavidC.Rankin And if everything in `main()` would be inside an infinite loop?
And you're right with the cast, thanks! I'll correct that.

@1k5 My example was a little bit inappropriate. It is more like an infinite loop.
I don't have the possibility to watch my memory usage. 
I'm just allocating one char in the examples. In my real program, there's a parameter for the length too, but it is not important for the alloc/free question here.

Comment: In bare metal with little microprocessors as I think your are using, you should really avoid using malloc if you don't need really and you know that your malloc implementation is good for your use. However you still can use malloc and typedef for data hiding. (You can use it to generate pointers to permanent typedeffed structures whose dimension is known only inside the module that uses it, so you can avoid to import definitions in every place where you use it)

Comment: If everything in `main()` was in an infinite loop, you MUST free the allocated block before the next iteration (if you are allocating each iteration) If you don't, you will just continue to allocate memory until you exhaust all the available memory and your program croaks. In the microcontroller world, if you are just talking about the infinite loop you end with -- then the block would just stay allocated until the board is reset. Once you enter your spin-loop (e..g the `while (1) { /* do nothing */ }` loop) the program is essentially over.

Comment: @Damiano I'm avoiding to use malloc on microcontrollers, but I'm using a JSON library called cJSON which uses malloc and I haven't found a good alternative yet.

Comment: Don't do dynamic memory allocation at all on such memory-constrained devices.  Ever.  If you're using a library that does it, stop using it.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule - do not use malloc style dynamic memory allocation in the very limited resources uC environment. Many industrial standards ban it completely.

The uC programming is significantly different from the big machine.

If you ignore this advice and decide to use malloc - the rule of thumb is - keep the memory as long as possble. Having 0x200 bytes of heap and frequently mallocing and freeing the memory will very quickly lead to the heap fragmentation and program crash.

Comment: I'm never using dynamic memory allocation in my own program code. But I've to use cJSON (https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON) for creating JSON Files, since I've not found a better alternative.

Comment: @FlorianMoser depending how complex the json is: https://github.com/zserge/jsmn In my projects I try to keep json as flat as possible. (it is not the problem for server size guys - just few lines of code more)

Answer (score -1):

If you are writing a bare-metal code for a micro-controller ,generally their has to be a Superloop ,which keeps your application running . 
Hence ,considering above statements one should always free the memory after its use ,as because of this Superloop the program will lead to overflow of memory and your application will crash.

Your above code is fine for running on OS , as OS will free the memory once the program is exited. 
But its always a good practice to free the memory as soon as its not in use anymore.